# ¿Cómo se fusionan dos dataframe en uno?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dos marcos de datos indexados en fechas que parecen tener un formato diferente:

`dowjones` :

```
    price   dc2 dc3 dc4 dc5
date                    
16/01/17    19929.62    19950.92    19850.32    19883.60    0
17/01/17    19848.82    19882.99    19775.35    19826.77    0
18/01/17    19822.73    19828.20    19739.00    19804.72    0
... 
15/01/19    23914.11    24099.14    23887.93    24065.59    0
```

y

`df_merging` :

```
New_Column
date    
2019-01-15  {'Australian Financial Review': nan, 'Financia...
2019-01-14  {'Australian Financial Review': nan, 'Financia...
2019-01-13  {'Australian Financial Review': nan, 'Financia...
```

Me gustaría fusionarlos para obtener una cosa como lo siguiente :

```
    prices  articles
2007-01-01  12469   What Sticks from '06. Somalia Orders Islamist...
2007-01-02  12472   Heart Health: Vitamin Does Not Prevent Death ...
2007-01-03  12474   Google Answer to Filling Jobs Is an Algorithm...
```

¿Sabes cómo puedo hacer? Gracias para su ayuda !

Answer (score 0):

En el enlace adjunto, se explica bastante bien esta función y se ponen muchos ejemplos:
[Enlace a merge and join](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.07-merge-and-join.html)